# how to set session variable in handler

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session

I am working in asp.net. I have to save a value in Session in handler. I am doing it like this

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            { 

    while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    sb.Append(sdr["FirstName"]).Append(" " ).Append(sdr["LastName"]).Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    if (sdr["Profile_ID"] != null)
                    {
                        int yy= Convert.ToInt32( sdr["Profile_ID"]);
                        context.Session["namekiid"] = yy;
                    }
                }
    }
```

reader is reading the values. But when compiler comes on "context.Session["namekiid"] = yy;"  it says "object reference not set to an instance of an object". I traced these lines reader is reading Profile_ID "3" and saving it in variable "yy" but when storing this variable value in Session it says "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is this code running at?

Comment: In handler.. ashx file

Comment: Is context null right when ProcessRequest runs?

Comment: how can I know this that context is null? Sorry for the silly question

Comment: well I'm assuming your code is being called from the ProcessRequest override which has context as a parameter. Can you place a breakpoint and see if the parameter is null? Can you post the entire function as well?

Comment: I didn't use  IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState in my handler that's why it was happening. But now its taking value. But again a problem is I want to save that profile_id  whose username is selected in textbox by the user. By above code it is selecting last Profile_ID in the database

Comment: You'll probably need to open a new question for your new problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

replace your this line with mine

```
 context.Session["namekiid"] = yy;


HttpContext.Current.Session["namekiid"]=yy;
```

Comment: and if I want to access this session variable in aspx.cs file then what should I write? int id=  Session["namekiid"]??

Comment: It is still saying Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I didn't use IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState in my handler that's why it was happening. But now its taking value. But again a problem is I want to save that profile_id whose username is selected in textbox by the user. By above code it is selecting last Profile_ID in the database

Comment: if there is pair of (profile_id,Username) then you can it as key,value(Hashtable,Dictionary) pair in session and you retrieved respected values.

Answer (score 0):

That's either because context is null or context.Session is null

Comment: I didn't use IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState in my handler that's why it was happening. But now its taking value. But again a problem is I want to save that profile_id whose username is selected in textbox by the user. By above code it is selecting last Profile_ID in the database